# how to edit labels in a textfield?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitextfield, uilabel

i am getting labels from previous view controller and showing that labels in next view controller but i want to make them edit in a text field, i set these labels user interaction enabled checked but it still not working

```
 -(void)setDataOnForm
{
    nameLbl.text=name;
    emailLbl.text=email;

    imageSelect.image=[MyCommonFunctions getImageFromDocuments:image];

    NSLog(@"image %@", image);

}
```

here is my previous view controller

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 user *worddc=[dataArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    profileVC *pvc =[[profileVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"profileVC" bundle:nil];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:pvc animated:YES];
    pvc.getid=worddc.user_id;
    pvc.name=worddc.name;
    pvc.email=worddc.email;
    pvc.image=worddc.image;
   [pvc setDataOnForm];

}
```

Comment: get textfield in the next view not label.

Answer (score 2):

Use UITextFiled not UILabel if you want to edit text.

Answer (score 0):

Make a UITextField in your second view and use

```
 [textField setText:name];
```